# After loop a post category in home page there is issue (wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, while-loop

I have 2 sections in my home page like this:

```
<section class="tours" id="tours">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <h2><?php the_field('tours_title'); ?></h2>
                <div class="row">
                <?php
                    global $post; // needed this

                    $temp = $wp_query; $wp_query= null;
                    $wp_query = new WP_Query(); $wp_query->query('cat=3' . '&showposts=5' . '&paged='.$paged);
                    if($wp_query->have_posts()): ?>

                        <?php while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); 
                        // get the latest blog entry
                        $img_id = get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_ID());
                        $alt_text = get_post_meta($img_id , '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true); ?>
                        <div class="col20">
                            <div class="tour-img">
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="tour-desc">
                                <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                                <p><?php the_field('short_description'); ?></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <?php endwhile; 
                endif; ?>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tours-bg">                  
                <video autoplay loop>
                    <source src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/file1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                </video>
                <div class="tours-overlay"></div>
            </div>
        </section>      
        <section class="about" id="about">
            <div class="about-content">
                <h2><?php the_field('about_title'); ?></h2>
                <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
            </div>
            <div class="about-bg">                  
                <video class="bv-video" autoplay loop></video>
            </div>
        </section>
```

After this query I don't get correct values in second section. How can be resolved that? In second section the value of `the_content()` is not getted from home page but from one of the posts from previous section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>` after your custom loop to restore the $wp_query and global post data to the original main query.

Reference: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_query

Answer (score 0):

Try to use echo  $content = get_post_field('post_content', $page_id); and check if it sort out the issue.

Comment: here $page_id will be your homepage id

Comment: I am a begginer to php, I didn't understand where have I to use it. I understand that the query affects baddly the rest of the page.

Comment: change <p><?php the_content(); ?></p> to :-

    <p><?php echo get_post_field('post_content', get_the_ID()); ?></p>